android native error by requesting static resources such as js, css, mp4
I'm using Android native webview and the server consisting of Apache web server, tomcat, spring framework. When I request static resources like js, css, mp3, png etc.. the native error shows that it is related to the static.
Android source following. (collecting logs using rollbar which is a rolling log tool).
@Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        QLog.d("[WebViewClient::onReceivedError()]");
        QLog.d("  >> url : " + request.getUrl().toString());
        QLog.d("  >> error : " + error.getErrorCode() + " / " + error.getDescription());

        int errorCode = error.getErrorCode();

        try {
            throw new RuntimeException("onReceivedError2");
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            CustomKeysAndValues keysAndValues = new CustomKeysAndValues.Builder()
                    .putString("function", "onReceivedError2")
                    .putString("url", request.getUrl().toString())
                    .putString("onPageStartUrl", onPageStartUrl)
                    .putString("errorCode", ""+errorCode)
                    .putString("description", ""+error.getDescription())
                    .putString("history", getPageHistory())
                    .build();
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCustomKeys(keysAndValues);
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);

            Rollbar rollbar = Rollbar.instance();
            rollbar.error(String.format("function: %s, url: %s, onPageStartUrl: %s, errorCode: %s, description: %s, history: %s",
                    "onReceivedError2",
                    request.getUrl().toString(),
                    onPageStartUrl,
                    errorCode,
                    error.getDescription(),
                    getPageHistory()
            ));
        }

        if( mOnPageLoadListener != null ){
            if( !(errorCode == -1 || errorCode == -6) ) {
                if ( !(request.getUrl().toString().contains(".mp4") || request.getUrl().toString().endsWith(".png")) ) {
                    mOnPageLoadListener.onPageError(PageError.networkError);
                }
            }
        }
    }


function: onReceivedError2, url: https://test2.tnmiot.co.kr:8443/images_theme/faq/21/FREEZER_ALARM.mp4, onPageStartUrl: https://test2.tnmiot.co.kr:8443/faq/VM1421, errorCode: -1, description: net::ERR_FAILED, history: [1:https://test2.tnmiot.co.kr:8443/me

Settings

Android + Server(Apache + Tomcat + spring)

I'm already setting the http and manifest (like http, authentication..) but nothing helpful.
